# iOS/Swift: Set Variable in AppDelegate from another ViewController (bluetooth/ble)

Tags: iphone, swift, bluetooth, singleton, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a Bluetooth LE application. In the application, the user migrates to Settings -> Bluetooth Peripherals to get a list of the BLE devices in range. They choose one of the devices by tapping on it which then sends the user back to the Settings view controller upon successful connection to the device selected.

Here are my questions:

1) When it comes to call backs such as didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService and didUpdateValueForCharacteristic, are these values only available when they are part of the view controller that is currently active?

2) How do I set a variable within the AppDelegate controller from another controller such as my PeripheralController when my user chooses the device they wish to connect to?

I need to be able to use the two call backs previously mentioned no matter where the user is in the application but only after they have selected a device to connect to.

3) Let's say the user closes the application after initially choosing a device to connect to. Where is this information saved? Is it saved?

4) Do I have to manually save it so when the application is launched again, the application connects to and starts listening for service requests from that device?

Thank you.

**Edit**
I edited the original post and separated out the questions, hopefully they are easier to see and understand now.

I was able to successfully answer question 2 however, I am still curious about questions 1 and I am still working on questions 3 and 4.

Comment: The typical approach is to create an object that manages your Bluetooth.  This object can be created in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and stored as a property on your AppDelegate.  This object can, for example, have its own protocol and you add view controllers as its delegate as required or use NSNotificationCenter to "broadcast" Bluetooth events.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** When it comes to call backs such as didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService and didUpdateValueForCharacteristic, are these values only available when they are part of the view controller that is currently active?

**Answer:** Yes, these call handlers are only available in the controller in which the delegate is part of.

**Question:** How do I set a variable within the AppDelegate controller from another controller such as my PeripheralController when my user chooses the device they wish to connect to?

**Answer:** The answer has multiple parts. First, the controller that you want to set the variable from must have a reference to the delegate. To do this in Swift, we do the following:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Next, we assign the value in the appDelegate the value that we want it to have:

```
self.delegate.var = "Our Value"
```

**Question:** Let's say the user closes the application after initially choosing a device to connect to. Where is this information saved? Is it saved?

**Answer:** The information is not stored that I am aware of.

**Question:** Do I have to manually save it so when the application is launched again, the application connects to and starts listening for service requests from that device?

**Answer:** Yes.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the answer of the first question but for the second one just put a var in the app delegate and try to chance it like so:

```
Appdelegate.nameVar = newInput
```

I am not really sure if this is possible.

P.S. Next time try to order your question so it is easier to read and refer to.